# How to suppress the Ubuntu software update notifier popup in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: upgrade

There is no operator and no keyboard connected on this self-service kiosk equipment, and we do not want any popups.

[image: software update notifier popup]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you provided, click the [Settings...] button, it has options to never check for updates there.

To do this in the terminal you need to find the files that are used for this, probably in cron somewhere. I just ran a little test and found these two files:

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` & `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`

I changed my settings in the GUI to **Never** and checked what these files were altered to as a result:

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";

cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

**Update-Package-Lists** Becomes **14** when you set it to update fortnightly.

Change your files to match and this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks, we will try that. Is there a way to remotely make the same setting thru ssh session? We have 70+ units in the field, where this setting needs to be updated.

Comment: Hi, I ran some tests on my machine and found the cron jobs that seem to be responsible for the update notifier gui so you can update this setting using SSH. I updated my answer with the details, let me know how you get on please?

Comment: P.S I don't know what the `Unattended-Upgrade` flag does.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades it does this.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your suggestions are very helpful. We will update the settings and check it.

Comment: If this solution worked for you please mark it as accepted.